ebpf-go getting `load program: permission denied: 0: (bf) r6 = r3: R3 !read_ok` error
I am trying to create an eBPF program using the ebpg-go package from cilium. I have had some minor success recreating this tutorial using the "accept4" system call instead of XDP as seen in the tutorial. I was getting a counter that increased everytime I sent a request to an API I had running localy. I've also been cross-referencing this tutorial from Datadog.
The cilium package has a 'ebpf2go' function that auto-generates a go file based on the ebpf c file you pass it.
I've now been attempting to modify the program to hook into the "read" system call instead of "accept4" and to load the details from that read system call into a hash table map instead of loading just a count into an array map. It should be said that I am still quite new to C and eBPF in general.
The eBPF program I have written (logger.c)...
//go:build ignore

#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

struct data_args_t {
    int fd;
    const char* buf;
};

struct {
__uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
__type(key, __u32);
__type(value, __u64);
__uint(max_entries, 100);
} active_read_args_map SEC(".maps");

SEC("kprobe/sys_read")
int syscall__probe_entry_read(struct pt_regs* ctx, int fd, char* buf, int count) {
    int id = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();

    // Stash arguments.
    struct data_args_t read_args = {};
    read_args.fd = fd;
    read_args.buf = buf;
    bpf_map_update_elem(&active_read_args_map, &id, &read_args, BPF_NOEXIST);

    return 0;
}

char __license[] SEC("license") = "Dual MIT/GPL";

The go file I've written (main.go)...
package main

import (
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "os"
    "os/signal"

    "github.com/cilium/ebpf/link"
    "github.com/cilium/ebpf/rlimit"
)

func main() {
    // Remove resource limits for kernels <5.11.
    if err := rlimit.RemoveMemlock(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Removing memlock:", err)
    }

    //--------------------------------------------

    // Load the compiled eBPF ELF and load it into the kernel.
    var objs loggerObjects
    if err := loadLoggerObjects(&objs, nil); err != nil {    //<--- Error is happening here!
        log.Fatal("Loading eBPF objects:", err)
    }
    defer objs.Close()

    //---------------------------------------------------------

    // Attach Hello to the read system call.
    opts := &link.KprobeOptions {}
    link, err := link.Kprobe("__sys_read", objs.SyscallProbeEntryRead, opts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Attaching kprobe:", err)
    }
    defer link.Close()

    tick := time.Tick(time.Second)
    stop := make(chan os.Signal, 5)
    signal.Notify(stop, os.Interrupt)

    type Output interface {
        fd() int
        buf() string
    }

    for {
        select {
            case <-tick:
                var valueOut Output;
                err := objs.ActiveReadArgsMap.Lookup(uint32(0), valueOut);
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal("Map lookup:", err);
                }
                log.Printf("%d system calls made...");
            case <-stop:
                log.Print("Received signal, exiting...");
                return;
        }
    }
}

Lastly, the auto-generated go file with from ebpf2go based on the above C file (logger_bpfel.go)...
// Code generated by bpf2go; DO NOT EDIT.
//go:build 386 || amd64 || arm || arm64 || loong64 || mips64le || mipsle || ppc64le || riscv64

package main

import (
    "bytes"
    _ "embed"
    "fmt"
    "io"

    "github.com/cilium/ebpf"
)

// loadLogger returns the embedded CollectionSpec for logger.
func loadLogger() (*ebpf.CollectionSpec, error) {
    reader := bytes.NewReader(_LoggerBytes)
    spec, err := ebpf.LoadCollectionSpecFromReader(reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("can't load logger: %w", err)
    }

    return spec, err
}

// loadLoggerObjects loads logger and converts it into a struct.
//
// The following types are suitable as obj argument:
//
//*loggerObjects
//*loggerPrograms
//*loggerMaps
//
// See ebpf.CollectionSpec.LoadAndAssign documentation for details.
func loadLoggerObjects(obj interface{}, opts *ebpf.CollectionOptions) error {
    spec, err := loadLogger()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return spec.LoadAndAssign(obj, opts)
}

// loggerSpecs contains maps and programs before they are loaded into the kernel.
//
// It can be passed ebpf.CollectionSpec.Assign.
type loggerSpecs struct {
    loggerProgramSpecs
    loggerMapSpecs
}

// loggerSpecs contains programs before they are loaded into the kernel.
//
// It can be passed ebpf.CollectionSpec.Assign.
type loggerProgramSpecs struct {
    SyscallProbeEntryRead *ebpf.ProgramSpec `ebpf:"syscall__probe_entry_read"`
}

// loggerMapSpecs contains maps before they are loaded into the kernel.
//
// It can be passed ebpf.CollectionSpec.Assign.
type loggerMapSpecs struct {
    ActiveReadArgsMap *ebpf.MapSpec `ebpf:"active_read_args_map"`
}

// loggerObjects contains all objects after they have been loaded into the kernel.
//
// It can be passed to loadLoggerObjects or ebpf.CollectionSpec.LoadAndAssign.
type loggerObjects struct {
    loggerPrograms
    loggerMaps
}

func (o *loggerObjects) Close() error {
    return _LoggerClose(
        &o.loggerPrograms,
        &o.loggerMaps,
    )
}

// loggerMaps contains all maps after they have been loaded into the kernel.
//
// It can be passed to loadLoggerObjects or ebpf.CollectionSpec.LoadAndAssign.
type loggerMaps struct {
    ActiveReadArgsMap *ebpf.Map `ebpf:"active_read_args_map"`
}

func (m *loggerMaps) Close() error {
    return _LoggerClose(
        m.ActiveReadArgsMap,
    )
}

// loggerPrograms contains all programs after they have been loaded into the kernel.
//
// It can be passed to loadLoggerObjects or ebpf.CollectionSpec.LoadAndAssign.
type loggerPrograms struct {
    SyscallProbeEntryRead *ebpf.Program `ebpf:"syscall__probe_entry_read"`
}

func (p *loggerPrograms) Close() error {
    return _LoggerClose(
        p.SyscallProbeEntryRead,
    )
}

func _LoggerClose(closers ...io.Closer) error {
    for _, closer := range closers {
        if err := closer.Close(); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Do not access this directly.
//
//go:embed logger_bpfel.o
var _LoggerBytes []byte

With the below files I can run the 'go generate' command to generate the auto-generated files. From there I can run 'go build' which gets me an executable just like in the ebpf-go tutorial. From there running the command 'sudo ./ebpf_logger' gets me the following error output.
2024/08/29 19:57:15 Loading eBPF objects:field SyscallProbeEntryRead: program syscall__probe_entry_read: load program: permission denied: 0: (bf) r6 = r3: R3 !read_ok (3 line(s) omitted)

From reading some of the other posts, I don't think I have any empty or 0 initialized variables, but I'm not sure where to go from here...

I believe you need to use bpf_probe_read to read data from that char*.

The full logs are not needed in this case to understand the root cause (nor would they give additional clues). See Dylan's answer below.

The root of the issue is due to your eBPF program not passing the verifier. The error 0: (bf) r6 = r3: R3 !read_ok indicates that you are reading from register R3 while it isn't initialized. In eBPF, function arguments are always stored in R1-R5.
However, the "entrypoint" program (the program that is attached to a hook point) is always called with exactly 1 argument, the context. So only R1 is set.
Your function signature is therefor incorrect:
SEC("kprobe/sys_read")
int syscall__probe_entry_read(struct pt_regs* ctx, int fd, char* buf, int count)

It should be:
SEC("kprobe/sys_read")
int syscall__probe_entry_read(struct pt_regs* ctx)

You are normally expected to cast the proper fields of the context into the function arguments you are after depending on the calling convention. libbpf provides a header with a bunch of macros to make this task easier: https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/master/src/bpf_tracing.h
You can use the BPF_KSYSCALL macro to get a result similar to what you were doing:
SEC("kprobe/sys_read")
int BPF_KSYSCALL(syscall__probe_entry_read, int fd, char* buf, int count)

BPF_KSYSCALL is specifically for syscalls, it deals with a few syscall specific quirks in addition to the argument casting. For non-syscall functions the BPF_KPROBE macro is recommended to do just the argument casting.
